# Can I use something like a tunnel for SSH in this Linux/Windows Remote Desktop scenario?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, rdp, tunneling

I have a Linux server (call it server-L) which i cannot directly ssh to it. In order to ssh it i should connect to a windows server(call it server-W) and then make ssh connection from it to my Linux server.

I want to know are there any methods so that I can make network connection or something like a tunnle over RDP of server-W and directly SSH to server-L on my computer? My main reason for this is avoid stuck in windows GUI!
[image]

 in order to be specific my constraint are:

1. I have a limited user on server-W for RDP
2. I have private key/root access to server-L
3. My desktop machine got windows OS

Comment: You want to tunnel SSH over your RDP session to Win Server?

Comment: It's too bad you don't have remote access to "Server-L": tunneling RDP over SSH is trivial.

Comment: Why not install an SSH server on the Windows machine and tunnel with that? There are lots of SSH Servers for Windows available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Server-W has RDS services you could utilise "RemoteApp" to launch applications directly - as for direct tunneling over RDP not sure that's possible.

Comment: This *should* work, if you're talking about publishing PuTTY as a RemoteApp on Win Server.  Not sure all the features in PuTTY/SSH would work, but a basic shell should be doable.

Comment: Indeed I was :).. Yeah that's true obviously wouldn't be able to utilise the port forwarding etc. unless of course you published those apps too